# I port scanned 80 and 443 and found them closed. Why can I still browse the internet?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, https

I have been trying to figure out why I cannot SSH to my raspberry pi from my laptop outside the pi's network. I port scanned and found only port 22 open. I got stuck with that and still do not know why I can't.

I saw that port 80 and 443 (http and https) are closed.

And I wondered why am I still able to browse internet webpages?

Comment: This port scanning you did, was it performed from outside "the pi's network" (where your laptop is), or actually within the network? May I suggest some light reading up on TCP/IP?: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

The ports are closed for incoming connections only. In fact, when you browse a website, you are typically not using port 80 (or 443) on your machine at all, but using some higer-numbered port to connect t port 80 on the machine serving the website you are visiting. For example right now `sudo netstat -al | grep stackoverflow` gives me

```
tcp        0      0 172.16.200.141:34984    stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
```

so my machine is using port 34984 to connect to the Stack Overflow server (which also hosts Ask Ubuntu).